# Strange behavior of SELECT SqlSrv Query with OR clause and php array

Tags: php, sql-server

Hello every one being very noob in querying database im come up with strange array behavior after using

```
select DISTINCT TEST,DIARY_NO 
FROM Laboratory.dbo.DEMAND_DETAILS 
WHERE DIARY_NO='RMU-442' AND (TEST='Bitumen Test' OR  TEST='Softening Point' OR TEST='Flash Point/Fire Point' OR TEST='Penetration of Bituminous Material')
```

in my php script

The array which is correspondence to that query is coming up like this

```
[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"}]
[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"},{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Softening Point","key":"tests"}]
```

Where as what i desired is

```
[{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Flash Point\/Fire Point","key":"tests"},{"id":"RMU-442","test":"Softening Point","key":"tests"}]
```

Any help regarding this would be great 
Thank you So much in advance

Comment: You have to show php script that produce your array

Comment: here is the code snippet pastebin.com/TDFMddCN

Answer (score 0):

Try with `IN`

```
WHERE DIARY_NO='RMU-442' AND TEST IN ('Bitumen Test','Softening Point','Flash Point/Fire Point','Penetration of Bituminous Material')
```

Comment: Still the same problem even with 'IN' if u would like i can share my script

Comment: @copticbag how many rows you are getting when you run this query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @copticbag try with `distinct *`.

Comment: im already using DISTINCT key word Sir !! the array as i have mentioned is coming in response when i send ajax get request if there is any way to merge this the two array into one or any other way to make it one array